# Не работает отправка файла через ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, html5

Не могу понять, почему не работает отправка файла, в консоли жалуется на  `data.append('fileFF[]', files[k]);`

Форма

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" class="fofm" action="" id="feedback-form">
Отправка файла
<input class="igroup-input" type="file" name="fileFF[]" multiple id="fileFF" accept="image/*">
```

```
$("#feedback-form").submit(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var data = new FormData;

  $.each($('[type="file"]').prop('files'), function (k, v) { // Добавляем файлы
      data.append('fileFF[]', files[k]);
  });

  $.each($('form')[0], function (k, v) { // Добавляем все поля, кроме файлов
      var title = $(this).closest('form')[0][k].name;
      if (title != 'files') {
          data.append(title, $('form')[0][k].value);
      }
  });

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "contact.php",
    data: data,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success: function(msg) {
      if(msg == 'ok') {
        $('.close, .overlay').css('opacity','1');
        $('.close, .overlay').css('visibility','visible');
        $('.close, .overlay').css('display','block');
        $('#page-input').css({'opacity':'0','visibility':'hidden'});
      }
      else {
        $('.close .window').html('<h5>Ошибка</h5><p>Сообщение не отправлено, убедитесь в правильности заполнение полей</p>');
        $('.close, .overlay').css('opacity','1');
        $('.close, .overlay').css('visibility','visible');
        $('.close, .overlay').css('display','block');
        $('#page-input').css({'opacity':'0','visibility':'hidden'});
      }
    }
  });
  return false;
});
```

Comment: А первый аргумент data.append так и должен быть в кавычках ?

Comment: Если сделать так data.append('fileFF[]', 'files[k]'); то файл вообще не отправляется

Comment: На первый взгляд проблема возникает еще до отправки AJAX в объекте data. Посмотрите через console.log() что находится в этом объекте непосредственно перед отправкой данных и посмотрите что приходит на сервер.

Comment: Жалуется на data.append('fileFF[]', files[k]);

Comment: А что именно пишет консоль ? как вариант перед data.append в $.each сделать console.log(typeof files[k]);

Comment: Да пошла ошибка Uncaught ReferenceError: files is not defined

Comment: а что именно пишет?

Comment: ну вот и подсказочка :) , если посмотреть код то там нет массива с именем files

Comment: Такс, и как правильно сделать? Подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: Вот Uncaught ReferenceError: files is not defined

Comment: я больше по Node.js , jquery плохо знаю, надо смотреть что такое переменная k, может надо просто сделать data.append('fileFF[]', k);

Comment: Да если сделать data.append('fileFF[]', k); то работает, но файл не отправляет(((

Comment: надо смотреть что в переменной k

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f7115ba5622ebaba88e6db045313c01942b026c8 Вот сам php файл

Comment: Все испробовал, все равно не работает(